# Help with two SQL Queries

Tags: sql, mysql

I’m having some difficulties with two queries. I can get some of the information but my problem lies in the some special conditions I just can’t seem to get right in the SQL statement.

The first query is in natural language defined:

**I’m going to find all the candidates who has acquired two qualifications but during the same time period, but from different institutes**

My Relational schema looks like this:

**BOLD** = primary key

*ITALICS* = foreign key

candidate     = (**candidateid**, name, birth, mail)

qualification = (**qualificationid**, *instituteid*, *candidateid*, datestarted, datefinished, degreename, major)

institute     = (**instituteid**, institutename, city)

The SQL I’ve tried to run is not very pretty (at this point) and not working either but it is:

```
select (candidate.firstname, candidate.lastname) 
from candidate, qualification, institute 
where (select count(qualification.candidateid) from qualification where qualification.candidateid = 2) 
and between qualification.datestarted and qualification.datefinished
and qualification.instituteid <> qualification.instituteid
```

I gives me an error and I’m pretty, almost certain that it is in the COUNT clause but I can’t seem to crack it to how to count the numbers of candidateid’s and set a condition to two (2) and then I’m pretty sure as well that there is a problem in my checking on the time period. They have to be in the same time period.
And by the way, the datestarted and the datefinished is in the DATE format.

My second query I’m having problems with is in natural language formulated like this:

**Find the names of the companies who have all made inquiries about the candidates but with an average age below 30 (for the candidates).**

My relation schemas look like this:

candidate     = (**candidateid**, name, birth, mail)

qualification = (**qualificationid**, *instituteid*, *candidateid*, datestarted, datefinished, degreename, major)

inquiry       = (**inquiryid**,*candidateid*, *companyid*)

The query I’ve tried is this:

```
select (company.companyname) as company
from company, inquiry, candidates
where company.companyid = inquiry.companyid
and inquiry.candidateid = candidate.candidateid
and (select avg(candidate.birth < (right(curdate(),5<right(birth,5)) from candidate)))
```

The BIRTH tuble is also described as a DATE field.

I hope you can help me out whit these two queries and if there is any question about 'em, please say so and I'll try to clarify.

Mestika

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    candidate c
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    qualification q1
        JOIN    qualification q2
        ON      q2.candidateid = q1.candidateid
                AND q2.datestarted = q1.datestarted
                AND q2.dateended = q1.dateended
                AND q2.instituteid <> q1.instituteid
        WHERE   q2.candidateid = c.candidateid
        )
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for you reply.

I get a SQL Syntax error in your query and it specifies that it is near the JOIN clause. I don't really know what the error is cause it seems correct to me.

Comment: Thanks Quassnoi, it works like a charm :-)

I'm a bit embarrassed that I couldn't find the error myself, it is quite obvious :-)
But thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

you other issue is using cartesian JOINS (listing the tables in the FROM clause separated by commas) instead of explicit JOIN (INNER or LEFT or RIGHT).  You may find [Understanding SQL Joins](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Understanding-SQL-Joins/) a good read.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to your first question: you have a few issues.  One is that you have to join qualifications twice, since you want to compare the values from one match with another.  Another is that your date comparison has no value to compare.  It should be `x between y and z` -- in your example. you have no `x`.

After you join twice, then you can modify your last line to say `qual1.instid <> qual2.instid`

More details if you want, but I think that might get you started.  As an aside, I find the SQL join syntax easier to deal with, but to each his own.  One issue it helps resolve is the gigantic cartesian join you seem to have, because you don't appear to have any join criteria.

Answer (score 0):

subquery q should get a list of all candidate ids that have at least one other candidate at a different institute finishing in the same time period.  The subquery is joined to the candidate table to get the names.

```
SELECT(c.firstname, c.lastname) 
FROM candidate c JOIN 
  (SELECT q1.candidate_id FROM qualification q1 
    JOIN qualification q2 ON (q1.institute_id!=q2.institute_id) 
    WHERE q1.datefinished BETWEEN $somestartdate AND $someenddate 
      AND q2.datefinished BETWEEN $somestartdate AND $someenddate)q
ON (c.candidateid = q.candidateid)
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply.

The issue is that I don't have a specific $somestartedate and a specific $someenddate but just to check if the two instance is within the same time periode. You can say that it have to be some kind of "dynamic".

Comment: @Mesticka: so how do you define time period? Do both datefinished values have to be in the same year? Or does there have to be overlap between q1's tenure and q2's tenure.  The first is easier.

Comment: I just need to specify: Is there a candidate which has acquired two different qualifications during the same time period.
But the two qualifications has to be for different institutes. I don't worrie about if it is a specific date or year, just that they are in same period or overlap in time